# hash function confusion

Tags: hash

[image]

Anyone know how to start this problem? I mean, I understand what a hash does, but I have no idea what this quesiton is talking about.

Any ideas on how to go about this?

Given:

- the hash function: h(x) = | 2x + 5 | mod M
- a bucket array of capacity N
- a set of objects with keys: 12, 44, 13, 88, 23, 94, 11, 39, 20, 16, 5 (to input from left to right)

**4.a ***[5 pts]***** Write the hash table where M=N=11 and collisions are handled using separate chaining.

**4.b ***[5 pts]***** Write the hash table where M=N=11 and collisions are handled using linear probing.

**4.c ***[5 pts]***** If M=11 can you find a value of N that generates no collisions hashing those keys?

Answer (score 1):

Use the equation h(x) to find the hash value of each key. This is the location in the array where the value is stored. Since, this is clearly homework, I won't explain linear probing or separate chaining or 4c.

M is the size of the array that you put the values in.

N is the number of objects that you're hashing.

Answer (score 1):

- You have a function which given a number (x) determines where that should go in a table.
- The table has a given size, N.  In the case of parts a and b of this question N is 11.
- M is 11 for questions a, b and c.  M is just a value which is plugged into the given formula `h(x) = (2x + 5) mod M`
- So given the number 12, `h(12) = (2 * 12 + 5) mod 11` => 7.  So the first result goes into bucket 7.
- You then work your way through the rest of the numbers in turn, working out what h(x) is for each.
- However, when you come to a collision (i.e. a scenario where the bucket which the number should go in has already been filled by a previous number) you need to select a different bucket for it.  Which bucked you select will depend on your overflow strategy.
- in question A your overflow strategy is separate chaining
- in question B your overflow strategy is linear probing
- if you're unfamiliar with these methods, watch these:

  - Separate Chaining: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IDqTof09ufg
  - Linear Probing: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g0n0Ep18DJc
- If C is taken as read I assume it means that take the numbers from the start of the list until you hit the first collision; however many numbers you already have in your bucket is the value for N.
- However, I believe question C I believe is a misprint.  I think it wants you to find a value for M which would allow the given list of numbers to all be assigned to a unique bucket (i.e. no collisions / no overflow strategy).

Comment: Regarding my last 2 points I'd encourage input from others; I may have got the wrong end of the stick as that question seems wrong to me, which may just be me.

Comment: how did you get (2*12+5)mod11 =>7?

Comment: oh wait, nm I got it.

but 
what happens when you have your array like all the numbers are at the end, but the beggining is empty. Do you restart to the beggining?

like if you have x x x 15 14 12, and it's supposed to go at the next one, would it be

10 x x 15 14 12?

Comment: Hey @WeadadadaAwda.  First question: 2 * 12 = 24.  24 + 5 = 29.  29 mod 11 = 7 (i.e. 11 goes into 29 twice (22) with remainder 7 (29-22).

Comment: Second question: Yes, like in PacMan if you go off one side you come back on the other. That's actually the reason for the MOD function in the formula.  If you do `x mod 5` and pass it numbers 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7 you get 0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2.

Answer (score 0):

Start by computing the hash of each key.